# Cannot get new posts form to appear

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

On Cloud9, I'm building an instagram clone in my journey of learning RoR. One of the steps listed (which is purposefully vague, to push students to reach out and learn vs just being given the answer) is to add the following:

```
= simple_form_for @post do |f|
=f.input :image
=f.input :caption
=f.input :submit
```

No errors kicked off, looks like it is working fine. Restarted the rails s. Then the following was written

"in this case, we want to create a new post. Add the `@post` variable to the new action."

So, I thought that meant in `posts_controllers.rb`, to add the following:

```
def new 
  @post = Post.create
end
```

So this is what's in my `posts` controller:

```
  class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @posts = Post.all
    end

    def create
      @post = Post.create
    end
  end
```

Everytime I get the following:

```
No route matches [GET] "/new
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First thing. in new action, we dont create post, we just initialize it. For that you should do @post = Post.new. Secondly if you can share your routes file. specific to posts resources.? does this line exists there. resources :posts

Comment: route.rb:

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
  
  root 'posts#index'
end

Comment: your routes file is ok. please do bundle exec rake routes. it will list all the routes for the application. can you see post for new action there /posts/new. secondly from where are you calling this new action. please share.

Comment: Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Actionposts GET    /posts(.:format)          posts#index
          POST   /posts(.:format)          posts#create
 new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
     post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
          PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
          PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
          DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
     root GET    /                         posts#index

Comment: Everything seems to be fine. Pleae can you share the url which you hit. It should be /posts/new

Comment: Just to confirm you are facing this issue locally.??

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo in the `simple_form`.

1. `imput` should have been `input`.
2. The URL was `/posts/new`, not just `/new`.
3. `=f.input :submit` should have been `f.button`.